# Create nested object array using data from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, filter

I'm making two GET requests and the data from the second one ("Links") is dependent on data from the first one ("Categories"). My goal is to create a new object array from both and sort the Links under the Category it's assigned to.

Ideally, I want the new obj array to look something like this:

```
return {
    "_Category": m.Category, // "Animals"
    "_RootID": m.ID, // "1"
    "_Child": { 
            "_Title": "" // {_Title: "Otter"}, {_Title: "Monkey"}, etc
            "_Link": "" // "otters.com", etc
    }
}
```

And when done right, the next Category grouping would be like:

```
    "_Category": m.Category, // "Fruit"
    "_RootID": m.ID, // "2"
    "_Child": { 
            "_Title": "" // {_Title: "Banana"}, {_Title: "Apple"}, etc
            "_Link": "" // "bananas.com", etc
    }
```

And so on.

I've been able to load all Links under `"_Title"`, but the problem is that they're not separated by Category. It looks like:

```
        "_Category": m.Category, // "Fruit"
        "_RootID": m.ID, // "2"
        "_Child": { 
                "_Title": "" // {_Title: "Otter"}, {_Title: "Banana"}, {_Title: "Monkey"}, etc
                "_Link": ""
        }
```

How can I distribute the Links from the second array based on the Categories that they're tied to?

---

**Code:**

```
const getCategories = `${something}/getByTitle('Some_Categories')/items?$select=ID,Nav_x0020_Group/Title,Category&$expand=Nav_x0020_Group`,

      getLinks = `${something}/getByTitle('Some_Links')/items?$select=ID,Title,Link,Category/Category&$expand=Category`;

   // Category from getLinks is looking at the Category from getCategories. The data is the same.

    axios.all([
        axios.get(getCategories, restHeaders),
        axios.get(getLinks, restHeaders)
    ]).then(axios.spread((cats, links) => {
        
        let filtLinks = [];
        
        links.data.d.results.filter((n) => {
            if (n.Category) {
                filtLinks.push({
                    "_Title": n.Title
                })
            }
        })

        let newCats = cats.data.d.results.map((m) => {
            return {
                "_Category": m.Category,
                "_RootID": m.ID,
                "_Child": {
                    // filter first by cats.ID, then map back to m.ID
                    "_Title": filtLinks,
                    "_Link": "test"
                }
            }
        })
        console.log(newCats)
        this.setState({
            cats: newCats
        });
    })).catch(err => {
    // etc
```

Here's a snippet of what `filtLinks` looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8CF5.png

getCategories: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS1Bm.png

getLinks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEsp2.png

The category from the `getLinks` picture is the same category group that I expanded in the `getCategories` pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered around with it a lot, and I was able to do it. Note - I changed some of the variable names around:

```
]).then(axios.spread((cats, links) => {
            let catsData = cats.data.d.results,
                linksData = links.data.d.results,
                newCats = catsData.map((m) => {

                    let cat = m.Category,
                        titlesArr = [],
                        linksArr = [];
                
                    linksData
                        .filter((n) => {
                            if (n.Category.Category === cat) {
                                titlesArr.push(n.Title)
                                linksArr.push(n.Link)
                            }})

                    return {
                        "_Category": m.Category,
                        "_RootID": m.ID,
                        "_Child": {
                            "_Title": titlesArr,
                            "_Link": linksArr
                        }

                    }
            })
            console.log(newCats)
```

[image]

I had to redact the information, but everything that's appearing under `_Title` does belong to the "De..." `_Category`, and the other Categories are similar.